# Is it always possible to find $\vec{x}$ in the system of equations $A^TCA\vec x=\vec{f}$ directly by solving $A^T\vec{x}=\vec{f}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been doing problem 12.2 of this pdf file from 18.06SC from ocw.mit.edu: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/graphs-networks-incidence-matrices/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses1.12prob.pdf

I was able to solve it after some tedious eliminations. In the solutions there seems to be a shortcut. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/graphs-networks-incidence-matrices/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses1.12sol.pdf

It says that I should perform row reductions on the augmented matrix $[A|f]$ and choose $x_3=0$ to represent a grounded node. I have tried row reduction but I get $$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-1\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &-1\\
0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0\\
0 &0 &0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

How shall I get the desired value of $\vec{x} $ from this? Furthermore I am wondering if it is always possible to find $\vec{x}$ in the system of equations $A^TCA \vec x=\vec{f}$ directly by solving $A^T\vec{x}=\vec{f}$?

Comment: in general, the solutions of both systems need not be the same.

Comment: @user251257: But are they in this case?

Comment: You can test it just by computing $A^T C A\vec x$ and $A^T \vec x$...

Comment: Yes, but if I did compute it correctly then it is not correct. But why where the solutions designed this way if this is not correct?

Comment: human error? the solution is just wrong. It probably meant to be find $A^T \vec z = \vec f$ and then $CA \vec x  = \vec z$.